# Counter variable over multiple classes

Tags: java

I've been attempting to create a counter and points variable which is counted over multiple classes but every time I try use it the counter doesn't seem to work.

In my main class I set out the counter as the following:

```
public static int counter = 0;
```

And in each individual class in order to change the counter I put the following:

```
package Test;

import static iagui.IAGUI.counter;

public class test1 extends AnchorPane {

    public int counter;

    public test1() {
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

(I removed the other parts of the code to not fill up the page with a block of code.)

I've tried manipulating the counter variable in each class but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Classnames should start with upper case character

Comment: You increment the wrong counter. remove `public int counter;` but this is bad practice

Comment: You are hiding the actual variable you intend to edit with a field in your `test1` class. So you now have two variables, both called `counter` and you edit the wrong one. It is hard to give you a concrete fix since you did not post the full code. Please read [mcve], thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments you should follow standard java naming conventions.  For the sake of simplicity I am assuming you have two classes, Main and Test1.  Main should possibly be singleton but I do not have enough information here to address that.

```
public class Main{
   private static int counter = 0;

   public static synchronized void increment(){
       counter++;
   }

   public static synchronized int getCounter(){
       return counter;
   }
}

public class Test1 extends AnchorPane{
    public void test1(){
        Main.increment();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AnchorPane class you need to define a static attribute (counter in this case). In addition, in order for the counter to be incremented after each new instance you need to define this increment in the constructor of the parent class:

```
public AnchorPane () {
    this.counter + = 1;
}
```

In addition, in order to manipulate the counter attribute, it is necessary to define the methods for this. It is recommended to define these methods in AnchorPane so that all child classes will have access to these methods. The code looks like this:

```
public abstract class AnchorPane {
    public static int counter = 0;

    public AnchorPane() {
        this.counter += 1;
    }

    public int getCounter() {
        return this.counter;
    }

    public void incrementCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter += counter ;
    }

    public void decrementCounter(int counter) {
        this.counter -= counter; 
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Test1 extends AnchorPane {

    public Test1() {
        super();
    }

}
```

In the main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnchorPane test1 = new Test1();
        System.out.println(test1.getCounter());
        AnchorPane teste2 = new Test1();
        System.out.println(test1.getCounter());
    }

}
```